# Can't react on abort on PrintDialog

Tags: c#, devexpress, report

I have a report and want to print it. At the moment I am using:

```
myreport.PrintDialog()
```

If I click "abort" on the Windows `PrintDialog` the report gets printed on the standard printer. 
How can I handle this abort? 
I just want to print on OK, but I can't handle the `DialogResult`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [`PrintTool.PrintDialog()`](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraPrintingPrintTool_PrintDialogtopic) Method;

> Runs a print dialog box used for selecting a printer, setting some
>   print options and printing the document.

```
Return value
Type: Nullable<Boolean> 
true if the user clicks OK in the dialog box; false if the user clicks Cancel;
```

[`How to: Print a Report`](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#xtrareports/CustomDocument5093)

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using DevExpress.XtraReports.UI;
// ...

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    // Create a report instance, assigned to a Print Tool.
    ReportPrintTool pt = new ReportPrintTool(new XtraReport1());

    // Invoke the Print dialog.
    pt.PrintDialog();

    // Send the report to the default printer.
    pt.Print();

    // Send the report to the specified printer.
    pt.Print("myPrinter");
}
```

Comment: This snippet exactly re-creates the OP's problem.  It is ignoring the return value of PrintDialog().

Answer (score 1):

Have you worked like this?

```
PrintDialog dialog = new PrintDialog();
if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    // do your printing process here
}
```